# Determining sample size for one-way ANOVA using Cohen's f

Tags: anova, sample-size

I have three different groups for which I want to use one-way ANOVA (assuming the prerequisites for ANOVA are all fulfilled). I also have pre-survey data and now I want to determine the sample size for one-way ANOVA using Cohen's f. There are many software packages to perform power analysis, but all of them look like a black box to me. I am interested in the formula (the relation between them). For instance, given effect size f, a number of groups, power (say, 0.8), and alpha (say, 0.05), what is the formula for n? A reference to papers/book that mentions this formula will be a great help. I have consulted ChatGPT, Bard, and some books and papers by Cohen but had no luck. Thank you